# is there a NSLocalizedIndexedCollation for mac like UILocalizedIndexedCollation for iOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, contacts

Need to do some grouping for a list of contacts. But couldn't find UILocalizedIndexedCollation for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `NoodleIPhoneTableView` and `JAListView`, both available at GitHub:

- https://github.com/MrNoodle/NoodleKit/
- https://github.com/joshaber/JAListView/

Screenshots:

[image: NoodleIPhoneTableView]

[image: JAListView]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd checked the code, seems only work for English.